# How To Add Border To a UIView With Mask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here's what I need to do to my two buttons.

[image]

and here's what I got right now.

[image]

What I'm doing:
- Set these up in IB inside a stackView.
- Add masks
- Add borders with width and color
- Add shadow.

The borders are being added but being cut-off as well by the masks.

Codes:

```
public func addCornerRadiusToCorners(
    _ corners: UIRectCorner,
    cornerRadius: CGFloat,
    borderColor: UIColor,
    borderWidth: CGFloat) {

    //        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //        self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor

    let size = CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: size)
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask

}

public func addDefaultShadow() {
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)

    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
```

Any idea how to achieve the result in the first photo?

EDIT: the border is being cut, the result was just got from the UI Debugger of Xcode. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add corner radius to you view on `viewDidAppear`

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentView: UIView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    segmentView.layer.cornerRadius = segmentView.frame.size.height/2;
    segmentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    segmentView.clipsToBounds = true

    segmentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    segmentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    segmentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    segmentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    segmentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    segmentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: Although this is not the answer I'm looking for, as it is easy to achieve and applies the rounded corners to both sides and not to two corners only, you gave me an idea to just make the TWO buttons overlap each other and that would create an effect to look like the target design. :D

Comment: @Glenn I have updated my answer. I hope, it will match your requirements. I have added 2 buttons also. But not added button images. You can add those.

Comment: Yea thanks for this! It's done. I just realized how easy it is when I saw your edit. I hate myself lol.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to clip ur view.

```
self.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set maskstobounds to the view layer

```
 segmentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```